# In google compute engine how to configure local git repo?

Tags: git, github, google-compute-engine

When a new project is started with GCE a local repo within the project is made for source code. I can push and pull from my computer to the google servers but I cannot get the VM instance running LAMP to push or pull to the local repo. 
From My local machine I add a remote server
     git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/[project-name]

after this git push and pull work fine. Within the GCE VM Instance
     git remote add ...
This does not work. I am asked for a username and password and cannot find it.

Any help is apprecaited. Thanks.

Comment: Have you authorized your account on LAMP stack VM using gcloud auth login command ? You can refer to this doc (https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-quickstartwhich) which has steps to configure cloud source repositories.